# Tooltip on sparse HighCharts Heatmap

Tags: highcharts

I have a sparse heatmap - sample: https://jsfiddle.net/fujigoko/yhd8a6ct/14/ - where not all cells have a data item.

[image]

```
  tooltip: {
    formatter: function () {
      var currentDate = new Date(0);
      currentDate.setUTCSeconds(this.point.x / 1000);
      return "current date: " + currentDate; // this.point.value
    },
    positioner: function () {
      return { x: 105, y: 55 };
    }
  },
```

The tooltip is supposed to show the X axis date corresponding to the mouse position and
I would like to be able to show the tooltip on every cell, including those with no data, without having to create cells with value zero in them.

Is this possible?

Comment: Achieving this will not be easy and will require some custom code, such as creating a custom tooltip from annotations. I'm not entirely sure if this is a better solution than using a null points, but I have prepared a demo that you can use as a basis https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/r7fv5aun/

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping for something simpler, but I will play around with this idea. If you post it as an answer I will accept. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the comment section, the concept involves creating a custom tooltip from the annotation, which is based on the mouse position. It requires some polishing, particularly for smaller chart sizes.

```
  chart: {
    type: 'heatmap',
    marginTop: 40,
    marginBottom: 80,
    plotBorderWidth: 1,
    events: {
      load() {
        const chart = this;
        let annotationTimeout;

        const removeAnnotation = () => {
          if (chart.annotationTooltip) {
            chart.annotationTooltip.destroy();
            chart.annotationTooltip = null;
          }
        };

        chart.container.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
          clearTimeout(annotationTimeout);

          const mouseX = event.clientX - chart.plotLeft,
            mouseY = event.clientY - chart.plotTop,
            xAxisValue = chart.xAxis[0].toValue(mouseX);
          let tickIndex = -1;

          chart.xAxis[0].tickPositions.some((tick, i) => {
            if (
              xAxisValue >= tick - chart.xAxis[0].pointRange / 2 &&
              xAxisValue <= tick + chart.xAxis[0].pointRange / 2

            ) {
              tickIndex = i;
              return true;
            }
          });

          const tickPosition = chart.xAxis[0].tickPositions[tickIndex];
          if (tickPosition) {
            const point = chart.series[0].points.find(point => point.x === tickPosition);
            if (point) {
              const date = new Date(tickPosition);
              removeAnnotation();

              chart.annotationTooltip = chart.renderer
                .label(date, chart.xAxis[0].toPixels(tickPosition) - 100, mouseY - 25, 'callout')
                .attr({
                  fill: '#ffffffd9',
                  padding: 5,
                  zIndex: 10,
                  r: 5,
                })
                .add();
            }
          }
        });

        chart.container.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
          clearTimeout(annotationTimeout);
          annotationTimeout = setTimeout(removeAnnotation, 500);
        });
      },

    },
  },
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dczk5rof/

Depending on the requirements, an alternative option could be using a kind of empty gaps detector and programmatically filling them with null points.

```
const data = [
  [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 1), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 1), 15],
    ...
];

function hasData(x, y) {
  return data.some(([pointX, pointY]) => pointX === x && pointY === y);
}

function findEmptySpaces() {
  const startTimestamp = Date.UTC(2023, 9, 1),
    endTimestamp = Date.UTC(2023, 9, 5),
    emptySpaces = [];

  for (let x = startTimestamp; x <= endTimestamp; x += 86400000) {
    for (let y = startTimestamp; y <= endTimestamp; y += 86400000) {
      if (!hasData(x, y)) {
        emptySpaces.push([x, y]);
      }
    }
  }
  return emptySpaces;
}

const emptySpaces = findEmptySpaces();

data.push(...emptySpaces.map(point => [...point, null]));

data.sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0]);
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Ly4r32gq/